# Show/Hide divs based on Time/Opening Hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, visibility

I am trying to show/hide divs based on opening hours.

The div `.open` contains the headline "Our store is open" and the other div `.close` contains the headline "Our store is close".

The store has the following opening hours:

Monday: 09:00-12:00 & 14:00-18:00

Tuesday: 08:30-12:00 & 13:30-18:00

Wednesday: 09:00-12:00 & 14:30-18:00

Thursday: 09:00-12:00 & 14:00-18:00

Friday: 09:00-12:00 & 14:30-18:00

Saturday: 08:00-11:30

Sunday: Closed

The timezone is Germany (UTC+1).

So during the opening hours the div with the class `.open` should be displayed and the other div with the class `.close` should be hidden.

During the closed times the div with the class `.close` should be displayed and the div with the class `.open` should be hidden.

I also tried to add special days when the store is closed for a whole day. E.g. December 24 & December 26.

I have tried so much but always failed, I hope someone can help me with this.
Really appreciate any comment on this as i search for a solution for hours now.

I have tried the following Code (it works, but only with start & end time – I have not managed to get the breaks in each day. Likewise, I didn't manage to decline the special days (December 24 & 26) as closed):

```js
var openHours = [
    {
        openHour: -1,
        openMinute: -1,
        closeHour: -1,
        closeMinute: -1,
    },
    {
        openHour: 9,
        openMinute: 00,
        closeHour: 18,
        closeMinute: 00,
    },
    {
        openHour: 8,
        openMinute: 30,
        closeHour: 18,
        closeMinute: 00,
    },
    {
        openHour: 9,
        openMinute: 00,
        closeHour: 18,
        closeMinute: 00,
    },
    {
        openHour: 9,
        openMinute: 00,
        closeHour: 18,
        closeMinute: 00,
    },
    {
        openHour: 9,
        openMinute: 00,
        closeHour: 18,
        closeMinute: 00,
    },
    {
        openHour: 8,
        openMinute: 00,
        closeHour: 11,
        closeMinute: 30,
    }
];

var d = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
var hour = d.getHours();
var mins = d.getMinutes();
var open = true;
var todayHours = openHours[dayOfWeek];

if (hour >= todayHours.openHour && hour <= todayHours.closeHour) {
    if ((hour==todayHours.openHour && mins < todayHours.openMinute) || (hour==todayHours.closeHour && mins > todayHours.closeMinute)) {
        open = false;
    } else {
        open = true;
    }
} else {
    open = false;
}

if (open) {
    $('.open').show();
    $('.close').hide();
} else {
    $('.open').hide();
    $('.close').show();
}
```

Comment: Which platform is your website using?  html, php or any CMS?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Apollo79 i added my code above :-)

Comment: @RobyRajuOommen i'm using webflow for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your code should work... The following works for me:

```js
const openHours = [{
    openHour: -1,
    openMinute: -1,
    closeHour: -1,
    closeMinute: -1,
  },
  {
    openHour: 9,
    openMinute: 00,
    closeHour: 18,
    closeMinute: 00,
  },
  {
    openHour: 8,
    openMinute: 30,
    closeHour: 18,
    closeMinute: 00,
  },
  {
    openHour: 9,
    openMinute: 00,
    closeHour: 18,
    closeMinute: 00,
  },
  {
    openHour: 9,
    openMinute: 00,
    closeHour: 18,
    closeMinute: 00,
  },
  {
    openHour: 9,
    openMinute: 00,
    closeHour: 18,
    closeMinute: 00,
  },
  {
    openHour: 8,
    openMinute: 00,
    closeHour: 11,
    closeMinute: 30,
  }
];

const d = new Date("February 14, 2022 18:00:00");
const dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
const hour = d.getHours();
const mins = d.getMinutes();
const todayHours = openHours[dayOfWeek];

let open = true;

if (hour >= todayHours.openHour && hour <= todayHours.closeHour) {
  if ((hour == todayHours.openHour && mins < todayHours.openMinute) || (hour == todayHours.closeHour && mins > todayHours.closeMinute)) {
    open = false;
  } else {
    open = true;
  }
} else {
  open = false;
}

if (open) {
  document.querySelector(".isopen.close").classList.add("hide");
} else {
  document.querySelector(".isopen.open").classList.add("hide");
}
```

```css
div.isopen {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  height: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}

div.isopen.open {
  background-color: green;
}

div.isopen.close {
  background-color: red;
}

div.isopen.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="isopen open">Open</div>
<div class="isopen close">Closed</div>
```